# How can I move firewall settings from one Debian Squeeze web server to another?

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I configured a Debian Squeeze virtual machine in VMWare on my laptop. I configured it with a very restrictive set of firewall rules using Firestarter. I then uploaded a copy of its disk image to use as a virtual private server on the internet.

On the internet version, I rather rashly removed my firewall settings via the following command:

```
apt-get purge firestarter
```

I’ve since realised I want to restore the firewall rules to their old state, which is still on the original virtual machine on my laptop.

My question is: how can I copy the firewall settings from the virtual machine on my laptop to the one on the internet?

I tried copying /sbin/iptables from the original virtual machine to the new one, but that hasn’t had any effect (according to the output of `iptables -L`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`, or you can once more install firestarter and use the config file from the old machine.

Comment: Ah, okay — I guess I could just copy everything from `/etc/firestarter` on the old machine to the new one. I’ll give that a try.

Comment: I think copying all the firestarter config files appears to have borked my firewall somehow, as I can no longer communicate with the server! However, `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` looked like they would have worked great, so I’ll be sure to use them next time.

Comment: Have this server the same IP address? If not, this can be a reason...

Comment: Ah! No, it doesn’t — I can imagine how that could have caused some issues.

Comment: Can you provide details on using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` when the server ip addresses differ? Is anything special required, or will simply loading the rules on the new server work?

Comment: You can review file, which was generated by iptables-save, if there is the old IP address. It would be changed to the new one. It will be in the case of DNAT, SNAT and other address manipulation, sometimes when you would like to restrict access to machine...